How to automatically get table create statement for Redshift serverless from Pandas dataframe
I have an S3 bucket which contains parquet files.
I need to analyse that parquet file and create the required table in Redshift serverless.
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
df = pq.read_table(f"s3://{bucket_name}/{s3_path}").to_pandas()
table_create_statement = pd.io.sql.get_schema(df, table_name)

Using the above code, I was able to get the create statement for the dataframe as table.
But the df columns contains numbers that are of 38 digits. where as the create table statement that I got contain the INTEGER data type which has numeric precision of 32 for that column instead of NUMERIC(38, 0) or DECIMAL(38, 0).
And for some columns, the table create statement have boolean type, where as the actual data contains numbers or strings - TRUE or FALSE
How do I get the table create statement that's compatible for Redshift serverless?

Don't believe there's a scripted way to convert the table definitions from one technology to another like you are needing outside of manually editing the definition before creating it in Redshift.  Are you trying to automate a process or is this a one off/one time need?

I'm trying to automate the process. Also the schema might change in future for which I need to alter the table and add columns.

Glue crawler will make a spectrum table for u

I ended up using duckdb library to get the schema of the parquet file
df = duckdb.sql(f"describe select * from read_parquet('{file_name}')").df()
col_type_dict = {col: col_type for col, col_type in zip(df["column_name"], df["column_type"])}

which is giving almost exact data types for the columns and on top of that made some changes for other data types.
